# Error: method verifyCredentials in interface AccountService cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android, android-studio, twitter

I am using the following code in my Twitter Integration App.

```
Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
            .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    //If any error occurs handle it here
                }

                @Override
                public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
                    // get the user details 

                }
            });
```

It is throwing following error.

```
error: method verifyCredentials in interface AccountService cannot be applied to given types;

required: Boolean,Boolean

found: boolean,boolean,<anonymous Callback>

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Can somebody please help me in resolving this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the documentation still specifies two version for the method 
VerifyCredentials(), one that takes callback as an argument and one that doesn't, still I have faced the same issues.

I tried to open the source code in Android Studio but it had only the version without the callback.

Here is how I solved the issue.

```
    //Getting the account service of the user logged in
    Call<User> call = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
            .verifyCredentials(true, false);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                //If any error occurs handle it here
            }
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
                //If it succeeds creating a User object from userResult.data
                User user = userResult.data;
                setProfilePic(user.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", ""));
                twitterLoginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Here is the link to Documentation : [Fabric Documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/twitter-core/1.4.0/com/twitter/sdk/android/core/services/AccountService.html)

Source : [Twitter Login Android](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/twitter-login-android-tutorial-using-fabric-twitter-login-kit/)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

On button click Listener's success method call this method:

```
TwitterSession session;

@Override
public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {

    session = twitterSessionResult.data;
    getUserData(session);
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

void getUserData(TwitterSession session) { 

    Call<User> call = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true, false);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

            User user = userResult.data;
            userID = String.valueOf(user.id);    
        }
    });
}
```